# What is the right function to add persons number to my cooking app?

Tags: flutter, final

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

enum Complexity {
  Simple,
  Challenging,
  Hard,
}

class Meal {
  final String id;
  final List<String> categories;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<String> ingredients;
  final List<String> steps;
  final int duration;
  final Complexity complexity;
  final bool isGlutenFree;
  final bool isLactoseFree;
  final bool isVegan;
  final bool isVegetarian;

  const Meal({
    required this.id,
    required this.categories,
    required this.title,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.ingredients,
    required this.steps,
    required this.duration,
    required this.complexity,
    required this.isGlutenFree,
    required this.isLactoseFree,
    required this.isVegan,
    required this.isVegetarian,
  });
}
```

Hallo, i have added the complexity of my meals to my meal app.
But, how can I add the number of persons? What do I need? I want to add, that the meal is for 1 or 2 or 3 persons.

```
Thank you!
```

Comment: Do you just want to add an extra variable ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.